# How to access a GlobalKTable outside of a kafka streams context in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'd like to access a global ktable in a context other than the kafka streams context.

As an example, I have this sample app:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

with this GlobalKTable configured

```java
@Component
public class Table {

    @Bean("myTable")
    public GlobalKTable<String, String> buildTopo(@Qualifier("ksConfig") StreamsBuilder builder) {
        return builder.globalTable("my-topic",
                Materialized.<String, String, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as(
                                "my-state-store" /* table/store name */)
                        .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
                        .withValueSerde(Serdes.String())
        );
    }
}
```

And this kafka streams configuration:

```java
@Configuration
public class KafkaConfiguration {

    @Bean("ksConfig")
    public StreamsBuilderFactoryBean kafkaStreams(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties,
                                                  @Value("${spring.application.name}") String appName) {
        var props = new HashMap<String, Object>(kafkaProperties.getProperties());
        props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaProperties.getBootstrapServers());
        props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, appName);
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
        props.put(StreamsConfig.COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 10 * 1000);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest");
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_DESERIALIZATION_EXCEPTION_HANDLER_CLASS_CONFIG, LogAndContinueExceptionHandler.class);
        var stateDir = kafkaProperties.getStreams().getStateDir() != null ?
                kafkaProperties.getStreams().getStateDir() : System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
        props.put(StreamsConfig.STATE_DIR_CONFIG, stateDir);
        var config = new KafkaStreamsConfiguration(props);
        return new StreamsBuilderFactoryBean(config);
    }
```

Now let's say I have a web endpoint:

```java
@Path("/api")
@Service
public class Web {

    @GET
    @Path("/test")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response test(@QueryParam("key") String key) {

        String value =  // get value from global ktable with Key

        return Response.status(200).entity(value).build();
    }
}
```

How can I get at the ktable from inside this `Web::test(...)` method?

I tried autowiring some prospective Kafka streams classes in `Web`, like `KafkaStreams` and `ProcessorContext`.   Spring throws an error saying it cannot find those beans.

Comment: Sounds like you want to use an [`InteractiveQueryService`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/kafka-streams.html#_interactive_queries) + [source](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/blob/main/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/binder/kafka/streams/InteractiveQueryService.java)

Comment: @OneCricketeer - I'd like to avoid using Spring Cloud if at all possible.  But this does give me ideas on how to get at the ktable

Comment: Is there a particular reason why? Otherwise, did you try `@Autowired GlobalKTable<String, String> myTable;`? Since that is the `@Bean` that you've created?

Answer (score 2):

The `InteractiveQueryService` is actually only needed when you are using spring-cloud because you can have multiple kafka-streams instances in one application there. In your case you can get access to the `KafkaStreams` object via `StreamsBuilderFactoryBean` and get the store from there:

```java
@Path("/api")
@Service
public class Web {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("ksConfig")
    private StreamsBuilderFactoryBean streamsBuilderFactoryBean;

    @GET
    @Path("/test")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response test(@QueryParam("key") String key) {

        String value =  getValue(key);

        return Response.status(200).entity(value).build();
    }
    
    private String getValue(String key) {
        QueryableStoreType<ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<String, String>> storeType = QueryableStoreTypes.keyValueStore();
        ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<String, String> store = streamsBuilderFactoryBean.getKafkaStreams().store(StoreQueryParameters.fromNameAndType("my-state-store", storeType));
        return store.get(key);
    }
}
```